# Inserting images in WordPress

Tags: images, wordpress.com

I can't believe I'm having to ask this basic a question. But I honestly cannot figure out how to insert a pre-hosted image into a WordPress post.

This is what my 'New Post' screen looks like:

[image: 'New Post' screen]

The big "Insert Photo" button directly inserts from my computer, but I want to insert an image hosted on Imgur.

Comment: Is that WordPress.com?  I've never seen a post editor that looked like that in a self-hosted site or on .com.  

Regardless, after clicking Insert Photo do you not get the Media Uploader which should have a "Insert Image from URL"?

Comment: @jb510: The post editor looks like that when logged into WordPress.com (for example, when viewing the WordPress.com "Reader") and then pressing "New Post" and then choosing the "Text" option.

Comment: The WordPress.com instruction are very clear on this: http://en.support.wordpress.com/images/#insert-an-image-from-the-web

What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: @jb510: The WP.com instructions that you refer to are talking about the first type of post-editor mentioned in my response (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/47208/38185).  But if you look at the screenshot provided by the OP, it is referring to the second type of post-editor in my response, which does not have an "Add Media" button.  IMHO, the current WP.com documentation is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two types of post editors inside WordPress.com.  I don't know the official names for them, so please excuse my choice of names below.

1. The "blog-level" editor, which you enter from within the Dashboard for your specific WordPress.com blog, and which is the "main" and full-fledged editor.
2. The "WordPress.com-level editor", which you can enter while logged into WordPress.com (for example, when viewing the WordPress.com "Reader") after pressing the "New Post" button.

Your screenshot seems to be of the latter, after choosing the "Text" option in response to "What would you like to post?".  It seems that this "WP.com-level editor" is rather limited.  It does not have an "Add Media" button, and only allows one to upload new images, without allowing one to choose existing images from the Media Library or to specify a URL for an externally hosted image.

I suggest that you do not use this "WP.com-level editor", and only use the "main, blog-level" editor.  This editor has an "Add Media" button, offering both an "Insert Media" option (from the Media Gallery), as well as an "Insert from URL" option.  You seem to be looking for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

In the right top of your editor window there should be a "text" tab. Pressing this gives you the current page/post as a code view. Here is a button `[img]` thar gives you the possibility of adding a image with href of choice.

An alternate solution is to add a image from a file in your media library. Then right click the image and edit the preferences for the image. The Advanced settings give you the HREF for the image and here you can set your imgur image.